# How does the scrapy send the web requests internally?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to figure out which package does the scrapy uses to send the web requests.

I have checked the source code in github,but i couldn't

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, internally scrapy uses [`twisted.web.http.HTTPClient`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1fd1702a11a56ecbe9851ba4f9d3c10797e262dd/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py), but there's a lot of machinery on top of it. Look for [arch overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#architecture-overview) for details

Comment: @SlamThanks for the update.But still i can't figure the package or the particular  line that sends the request to the web